# Listing Files from Azure File Service

Tags: azure, azure-files

I have uploaded files to a folder on my Azure file service account.  Now I would like to list those files.  When the code reaches this line

```cs
FileResultSegment resultSegment = await dir.ListFilesAndDirectoriesSegmentedAsync(token);
```

It closes.  No error is thrown, so I cannot figure out the issue.  The full method is below.  Has anyone got this to work?

```cs
public async void ListFiles() 
{
  const string clientShare = "clientshare";
  const string profileDirectory = "profiledirectory";
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
  CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
  CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference(clientShare);
  CloudFileDirectory root = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
  CloudFileDirectory dir = root.GetDirectoryReference(profileDirectory);

  if (share.Exists())
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Share Exists");
  }

  if (dir.Exists())
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Profiledirectory Exists");
  }


  Console.WriteLine("List Files/Directories in root directory");
  var results = new List<IListFileItem>();
  FileContinuationToken token = null;
  try
  {
      do
      {
          FileResultSegment resultSegment = await dir.ListFilesAndDirectoriesSegmentedAsync(token);
          results.AddRange(resultSegment.Results);
          token = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;
      }
      while (token != null);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      Console.ReadKey();
  }

  // Print all files/directories listed above
  foreach (IListFileItem listItem in results)
  {
      // listItem type will be CloudFile or CloudFileDirectory
      Console.WriteLine("- {0} (type: {1})", listItem.Uri, listItem.GetType());
  }
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code from where you're calling this method? My guess is that you would need to await this method.

Comment: var pictureHelper = new PictureHelper();
            pictureHelper.ListFiles();

Comment: Try something like `await pictureHelper.ListFiles();`.

Comment: You  are correct.  It works now.  Thanks